# what is meaning of "independent values of a random variable"?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I need some help with basic statistics terminology. Could someone please explain in layman terms the meaning of "independent values" regarding a random variable?

Perhaps a six-sided die (with sides numbered 1 to 6) is good to use as an example.

Assume a random variable is the time function `x` defined as the number resulting from the throw of the die, when the die is thrown multiple times.

If we throw the die twice, what are the independent values of the time function x?

Is it the set of values 1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6 (so, there are 12 independent values?)?

Or, if the result of the two die throws is 2 and 5, is the set of independent values for x equal to 2,5 (so, there are 2 independent values?)?

Or, something else?

Comment: You can understand independence like this. There are functions $x_1, x_2,...$ that give you the result of the first, second, ... throws of the dice, respectively. These functions depend on the set-up of the universe, or whatever, they depend on something which is not relevant to the problem, something unknown. Independence is saying that $x_1$ doesn't depend on $x_2$, ... This means that the unknown things of which $x_1$ depend are anything but the value given by $x_2$. Are you going to study random variables as measurable functions? If so, there is a more precise way of seeing independence.

Comment: Thanks Karene, can you work in somehow use of the term "set of independent values" for x? That is, give a simple example?

Answer (score 1):

Two events $E_1$ and $E_2$ are called "independent" if knowing the result of one event gives you no information about the other, that is, the probability that $E_2$ happens is unchanged by the knowledge of whether or not $E_1$ happens, and vice versa. Formally this is written as the four conditions:

$P(E_1|E_2) = P(E_1)$

$P(E_1|\neg E_2) = P(E_1)$

$P(E_2|E_1) = P(E_2)$

$P(E_2|\neg E_1) = P(E_2)$

In fact, using $P(E_1|E_2) = \frac{P(E_1 \cap E_2)}{P(E_2)}$ and $P(\neg E) = 1-P(E)$, assuming none of the relevant probabilities in the denominators are zero, one can see that these conditions are each equivalent to $P(E_1)P(E_2) = P(E_1 \cap E_2)$, which is the usual definition of independence of the two events.

Two random variables are then independent if each event in terms of one random variable is independent from each event in terms of the other. For example, if $X$ is the roll of the first die and $Y$ is the roll of the second, we would expect the events $\{X>3\}$ and $\{Y \text{ is even}\}$ to be independent.

Comment: Thanks Dustan, I understand independence. Can you help me understand what the `set of independent values` for x would be, in a simple example?

Comment: Can you put that in context? I'm not sure if I've heard that phrase before.

Comment: For example: A time function x has Y independent values in the time interval T. I'm trying to figure out if each value of x (e.g. xi) has N outcomes (e.g. N=6 possibilities for the throw of one die), how many independent values Y exist in interval T (e.g. assume we can roll the die two times in interval T)?

Comment: This is really confusing to read. Are you saying you're trying to figure out what $Y$ is?

Comment: Yes. For example, is Y=2 in my simple example of throwing a die two times?

Comment: I don't see anything in your prompt which indicates what $Y$ has to be. If you are rolling the die twice, then yes, $Y$ is 2.

Comment: @user119612 But to add what Dustan said above so that you are clear. The independence is apparent not in the number of throws but one the circumstances. For example if the second time you throw the dice, you throw it against the wall if the first throw was even, and you throw it against a pillow the second time if the first throw was odd, then the two throws are not (necessarily) independent.

Answer (score 0):

The set of independent values are just the possible outcomes of two die rolls:

$\{(1,1),(1,2).....(5,6),(6,6)\}$ The "independent" part of this really only means that the value of the first die roll does not affect the value of the second die roll.

An example of where this is not the case, i.e. not independent throws, would be the an unusual situation like below:

1. If the first die throw is an even number, the second throw will be an odd number
2. Vice versa

In that case, the set of *dependent* values would be:

$\{(1,2), (1,4), (1,6), (2,1), (2,3), (2,5)....(5,6),(6,5)\}$